# InfoPath Contact Selector in SharePoint, Form Postback error

Tags: infopath

I have created a InfoPath form with a Contact Selector. After I publish the form, I opened it to create a new form.

I entered a valid username and "Check Names" in the Contact Selector, it is giving me a error message "Error While Submitting Data to Server" 
I checked the Event Log and It says, " There was a form postback error" ...

Can anyone help !!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint (Install, Updates, CUs, SPs)?